# reading input from a specific device python

Tags: python, input, device

If i have two keyboards (default keyboard and an RFID reader) in my Linux machine
Using python how can I know from which device the input is coming from ?

I can read my input using the

```
input()
```

but i need to distinguish between the two devices

Comment: How your RFID is connected to your computer? By usb port?

Comment: yes both are on usb ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the RFID reader works on USB, if that's the case, should be treated like an input device as well as the HID Keybord (I'm assuming HID by your default).

I'm using evdev in python to do something similar for myself. 
You can find the documentation here: http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events

It has lots of simple and useful examples, like identify and read from multiple devices asynchronously.
I found it very easy to use.

Comment: Any chance there's a solution for NT-based systems? Doesn't seem like Windows has an equivalent for `evdev` cause of how it registers HID devices...